# history missing commands

Tags: shell, command-history

When I do this `history > myhist.txt`, I got all the list of commands, where the first column indicates the number of the command

[image]

However, for example, the command number 208,209, 211, 213,214, 215, 216, 217 are missing,

why is that? I remember executing another command around those lines , but those are the ones missing

Comment: Which shell are you using? What history options have you set for that shell?

Answer (score 0):

Some shells just record a command once if you repeat it several times in a row.